# Xamarin UITabBar returning unexpected size for SizeThatFits()

Tags: ios, size, xamarin, uitabbar

I have the following code in the parent view:

```
public override SizeF SizeThatFits(SizeF size) {
  UIView bar = this.tabBar;
  SizeF zero = new SizeF();
  SizeF r = bar.SizeThatFits(zero);
  Debug.WriteLine("returning size " + r.Width.ToString() + " " + r.Height.ToString());
  return r;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
2013-12-07 10:45:27.719 GraCalcIOS[8138:a0b] returning size 0 49
[0:] returning size 0 49
```

Just to make sure, I wrote the equivalent code directly into objective C, and the returned width is indeed 320.  The height is correct.

Can anyone explain?